# Mod Rewrite on Apache server returns 404 and cannot apply the rule pattern

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a mod rewrite to work, currently I get 404s.

Here's the rule :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/portfolio/([\w-]+)$ `index.php?portfolio=$1`
```

I input `example.com/portfolio/derp` and get a 404 when I want `index.php?portfolio=derp`.

Here's the rewrite log file :

```
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/derp
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/derp -> portfolio/derp
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'portfolio/derp'
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!=on' => matched
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => matched
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] rewrite 'portfolio/derp' -> 'http://example.com/portfolio/derp'
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://example.com/portfolio/derp
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] escaping http://example.com/portfolio/derp for redirect
[www.example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] redirect to http://example.com/portfolio/derp [REDIRECT/301]
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/derp -> portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'portfolio/derp'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!=on' => matched
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='example.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/derp -> portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^/portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/derp'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/derp -> portfolio/derp
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '(^|/)\.' to uri 'portfolio/derp'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#9fdb898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/404.html -> 404.html
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^' to uri '404.html'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='!=on' => matched
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='example.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/404.html -> 404.html
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^/portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri '404.html'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/404.html -> 404.html
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '(^|/)\.' to uri '404.html'
[example.com/sid#9d9d4b0][rid#a010568/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/404.html
```

Hope you can make sense of that. It could be written in Japanese as far as I'm concerned.

OK I've stripped down the `.htaccess` to just this :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^portfolio/([\w-]+)$ index.php?portfolio=$1
```

Removing the leading slash , this does load index.php but it looks for all the linked stuff pics , css stylesheet ect in /portfolio when they're in the root.

Here is the log for that rewrite :

```
   myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/derp
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/derp -> portfolio/derp
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/derp'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/portfolio' pattern='!-d' => matched
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/html/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/portfolio' pattern='!-f' => matched
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] rewrite 'portfolio/derp' -> 'index.php?portfolio=derp'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?portfolio=derp -> uri=index.php, args=portfolio=derp
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/html/index.php
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip document_root prefix: /var/www/html/index.php -> /index.php
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#8656878/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/index.php -> index.php
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#8656878/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'index.php'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#8656878/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/index.php
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/indexstyles.css
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/indexstyles.css -> portfolio/indexstyles.css
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/indexstyles.css'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86518a8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86518a8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/jquery-1.7.1.min.js -> portfolio/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86518a8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'

myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86518a8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/scripts/all.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/scripts/all.js -> portfolio/scripts/all.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/scripts/all.js'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/scripts/jquery.history.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/scripts/jquery.history.js -> portfolio/scripts/jquery.history.js
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/scripts/jquery.history.js'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/leoimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/leoimg.png -> portfolio/img/projectimg/leoimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/img/projectimg/leoimg.png'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/regformimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/regformimg.png -> portfolio/img/projectimg/regformimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/img/projectimg/regformimg.png'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/fileupimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/fileupimg.png -> portfolio/img/projectimg/fileupimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/img/projectimg/fileupimg.png'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/carimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/img/projectimg/carimg.png -> portfolio/img/projectimg/carimg.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/img/projectimg/carimg.png'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#86588c0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/portfolio -> /var/www/html/portfolio/img/chromeicon.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/portfolio/img/chromeicon.png -> portfolio/img/chromeicon.png
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/html/] applying pattern '^portfolio/([\w-]+)$' to uri 'portfolio/img/chromeicon.png'
myip - - [11/Feb/2012:20:58:32 +0000] [mydomain.com/sid#840f4b0][rid#864d898/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/html/] pass through /var/www/html/portfolio
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `/` from the start of the rule; you've got this in a per-directory context (either an `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` block) so there's no leading slash.

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([\w-]+)$ index.php?portfolio=$1
```

You may also have some issues with your other rules once you fix this - give that a try but if it's still broken, can you provide the rest of your config?

Comment: Removing the leading slash directs to portfolio.php ... I'll pop the whole ht access up .

Comment: ok , I stripped down the `.htaccess` to just this `RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^/portfolio/([\w-]+)$ index.php?portfolio=$1 ` and with the leading slash I get a 404 without 'portfolio.php'

Comment: The leading slash will never ever work in a per-directory context - still needs to be removed.

Comment: updated answer with new log

Comment: @FrankAstin It's serving `index.php`: `pass through /var/www/html/index.php`.  The browser's even sending a request for `indexstyles.css`; there's nary a mention of a file named `portfolio.php` in that log.  Are you certain it's being used?

Comment: Your right Shane , it is loading index.css  (I have a css-less file called portfolio.php which looks similar) . Anyway it's not loading index.css or anything else linked to the file  .

Comment: it's looking for the linked files in portfolio/ when they're all in the root dir . Is that easy to fix ?

Comment: @FrankAstin Oh, gotcha - the client browser is in that "fake" `/portfolio` directory, even though it's talking to `/index.php`, and the pointers to the resources are all relative - so it's putting in those requests for `/portfolio/`, since it thinks it's in that directory.  You've got two options: 1) Make your rewrite rule into a redirect, telling the client browser that it's actually talking to `/index.php`, changing the address bar; add `[R]` to the end of the `RewriteRule`.  2) Change the HTML that's generated in PHP to absolute paths. Add the leading slash: `<script src="/scripts/all.js">`

Comment: Changing it too absolute paths has done the trick . Thanks for all your help Shane .